# Passing a reference to a function in SML

Tags: sml

i would like to pass a reference to a function `foo` in `sml` and change its value. consider the following scenario:

```
val x = ref 5; 
foo 3 x; 
(* now x will be 3 *)
```

is it possible in `sml`? i know that `sml` does not have variables so i am not sure its possible. i would like to do that way in order to create tests such as:

```
val test1 = (foo (seq 2) = 2); 
val test2 = (foo it = 2);
```

it won't work because `it` will contain the output of `test1` (its boolean value). i would like to pass a reference `x` and change it every single time.

```
val x = ref 0;
val test1 = (foo (seq 2) x = 2); 
val test2 = (foo (getnext(!x)) x = 3); 
val test3 = (foo (getnext(!x)) x = 4); 
val test4 = (foo (getnext(!x)) x = 5);
```

`getnext` will get the next value and `foo` will insert it into `x`, beside from returning the value so it can check the equality.

Comment: Leaving aside the other questions, threading a mutable state through individual unit tests is always a Bad Idea(TM). Make your unit tests set up their data independently, your future self will thank you. Try an existing unit testing module to make things _slightly_ easier, e.g. https://github.com/kvalle/sml-testing

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with

```
fun foo v r = (r := v; v)
```

?